# Как зайти в аккаунт гугл с помощью requests python?

Tags: python, requests, google-account

Я написал программу на питоне, которая должна заходить в гугл аккаунт. Вот её код.

```
r = requests.post(
    "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/password/empty",
    {"passwd" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "LOGIN"},
    {"User-Agent" : "Mozila/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"}
)
```

Однако, гугл выдаёт пустой ответ со статусом 204, и я так понял, что я написал неправильные имена параметров. Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо написать вместо имён passwd и email?

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что 204- не верный ответ?)

Comment: Рекомендую поместить в вопрос конкретный текст ответа Google.

Comment: @Сергей 204 - это HTTP "No content"

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014, спасибо, я более с системной точки зрения  для новичка дал совет, чтобы он в будущем вопросы задавал сразу точнее и имел больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: {"passwd" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "LOGIN"} что это data или json?

Comment: @Cергей Шашко это data

Comment: datа={"passwd" : "PASSWORD", "email" : "LOGIN"} datа именованный параметр  requests.post.